Why is ’‘was’‘ used in the sentence in brackets?

The referential theory of meaning says that Santa Claus exists and is
an abstract object; furthermore (and this was the point of this
metaphysical excursus), the proper name Santa Claus is provided by
this doctrine with a referent, which it must have if the referential
theory of meaning is to be true.

This sentence is from Meaning: A Slim Guide to Semantics chapter 2

What verb would you prefer? If you wonder why it's not "is", it's referring to the point in past time when the excursus started. But you need to say in the question what your problem is.

It's entirely an arbitrary stylistic choice whether to refer to such current / extremely recent utterances using Present or Past tense. Consider how often the verb forms in things like That's what I mean / meant and He says / said he's going soon are equivalent and interchangeable.

An excursus is a digression, like leaving the trail on a hike in order to go see a small lake that is away from the beaten track, before returning to the trail.  At the lake you turn to your hiking companion and point to the lake and say  "this was why we left the trail. I wanted you to see this lake."  The past tense is in a statement about the reason for leaving the trail, which happened a while ago.
P.S. The situation explains the choice of past tense, but the past tense is not required there.
